# JOIN ON Coalesce(Formula1,Formula2,Formula3)

Tags: mysql, join, coalesce

Using MySQL, I'm trying to do a `JOIN` similar to how you would use a `JOIN` with `OR` statements like:

```
JOIN bioguide ON (bioguide.fulldistrict=house.districtname) OR
(left(bioguide.firstname,3)=left(house.first,3) AND bioguide.lastname=house.last) OR
(bioguide.fulldistrict=house.districtname AND bioguide.lastname=house.last)
```

As you probably know, the problem with doing it this way is that if a bunch of different ways work, you get multiple results per row.

My hope is that there's a way to use the `JOIN` and use it the way the `COALESCE`function works, essentially stating (even though it doesn't work):

```
JOIN bioguide ON COALESCE(bioguide.firstname=house.first AND
bioguide.lastname=house.last),(left(bioguide.firstname,3)=left(house.first,3) AND
bioguide.lastname=house.last),(bioguide.fulldistrict=house.districtname AND
bioguide.lastname=house.last))
```

If that worked, it'd be telling SQL to first `JOIN` on `(bioguide.firstname=house.first AND bioguide.lastname=house.last)` then on `(left(bioguide.firstname,3)=left(house.first,3) AND bioguide.lastname=house.last)`, etc.

Is something like this possible? Please let me know if other information would be helpful.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You can structure the query with the different matches in different tables, and then use `coalesce()` in the select to get what you want:

```
select coalesce(bg1.col1, bg2.col2, bg3.col3)
from . . . left outer join
     bioguide bg1
     on bg1.fulldistrict=house.districtname left outer join
     bioguide bg2
     on left(bg2.firstname,3)=left(house.first,3) AND bg2.lastname=house.last left outer join
     bioguide bg3
     on bg3.fulldistrict=house.districtname AND bg3.lastname=house.last
```

This can still result in multiple rows, if there are multiple matches for one of the comparisons (if the same row in `bioguide` matches all three, you have no problem with duplicated rows).

If so, then judiciously use a `group by`:

```
group by <id column that identifies each row in the result set>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you think of any way to do it without creating multiple tables?